# loading listview twice?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an activity on the top of it there are some buttons from which when a button pressed it  loads the dialog with country list and when user choose choose the country it will load the channel list below buttons.

so when activity start it shows blank screen until user choose the country

so i want to show a list when activity will start and then same procedure will follow as above.
but how can i load two different listview?

i tried

```
     acivity start
     load the default country channel's list
     buttonclick listener
     perform click {
     load the another list
     }
```

using the base adapter class found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455447/listview-not-refreshing-how-to-clear-the-listview-items).

Comment: I don't understand what kind of problems you have. Do you want to replace existing listview with new one?

Comment: yes when activity start it will load the default country channel's list say "USA channels list" and when user choose country load the new list of that country channels list.

Comment: So I guess your question could be: "how to refresh a listview with new content, or how to show a new listview"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch adapter to current list (this is the easy way to do it)

OR

In your android xml file, where you create your activity, create two listviews with different ids. First listView will have `android:visibility="visible"` (this one will be shown first) and the second one will have `android:visibility="gone"`(you will make this visible when you perform the click). 
When you want to switch the lists, just set first listview visibility to `View.VISIBLE` and the other one to `View.GONE`, from code.
Don't forget to switch adapters for different lists (this may be a bug source)

Answer (score 0):

I would do following

1. Have a flag like `isCountrySelected`
2. Change your adapter and onitemclick handler so that according to `isCountrySelected`, you either load channel list or country list.